# How to build ionic application using cocoonjs webview+?

Tags: javascript, android, ionic-framework, cocoonjs

The webview+ from cocoonjs gives a huge performance boost to my ionic application that uses a good amount css3 animations. I want to be able to build my application using webview+ from cocoonjs.

The [instructions](https://github.com/ludei/webview-plus) are straight forward and the commands don't throw an error but once I load the application on the device it's still using the default webview.

I'm thinking it has something to do with `android.json` or the `config.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging around in the java code, it looks like it was completely my fault I was trying to view the application on an emulator. There are issues with the current version of cocoonjs webview+.

> Launching the Webview+ inside android's emulator can lead to an application crash. Use a real device for testing.